# Why is Observable a class and Observer an interface?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

I am fairly still new to Model-View-Controller stuff and this just crossed my mind. Why is the Observable class a class to be extended and the Observer class is an interface? What's the purpose of doing that?

Comment: http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/observer-design-pattern/ .. refer to this.

Comment: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer for additional reference.

Answer (score 8):

As you can see in the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) the class *Observable* was added to the JDK in version 1.0. It might be a bit outdated. But we're talking about the JDK, so the class is still there because the JDK keeps all deprecated code until humanity is perished.

If you have a look at the [Observer Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer) then you may have realized that there is no *Observable* class. Instead it is named *Subject*. The *Subject* and the *Observer* are often shown as classes, but rather used as **interfaces**. And there is the problem with the outdated Observer Pattern implementation in the JDK. The *Subject (Observable)* is a class and must be subclassed. So you run into the problem that you cannot subclass from another more important class. Java only allows **single inheritance.**

**Best advice:** Don't use this outdated implementation.

**Two alternatives:**

- program your own implementation of the Observer Pattern based on interfaces
- have a look at all these listener implementations in the JDK, which actually implement the Observer Pattern in a somewhat modern way